# Separating wishlist and compare on category pages

Tags: magento2

I'm working in `catalog_category_view.xml` and `Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml`, trying to move the "Add to Wishlist" button to the top of each product item while keeping the compare button with Add to Cart.

How might I accomplish this? I can reposition them as a pair (by getting the 'addto' child block, but I've been unable to render them independently.

Answer (score 0):

So rather than *moving* each button, I ended up adding a second Wishlist button manually in `Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml` like so:

```
    <div data-role="add-to-links" class="actions-secondary"<?= strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-secondary') ? $position : '' ?>>
      <?php if ($this->helper('Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data')->isAllow()): ?>
         <a href="#"
            class="action towishlist"
            title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Wish List')); ?>"
            aria-label="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Wish List')); ?>"
            data-post='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getAddToWishlistParams($_product); ?>'
             data-action="add-to-wishlist"
             role="button">
               <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Wish List') ?></span>
         </a>
      <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
```

Then I removed the original Wishlist button:

`<referenceBlock name="category.product.addto.wishlist" remove="true" />`